# SMTP or PHP mail on VPS ( Or Physical Severs) - A Social Networking site

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am developing a social networking site. It has functionality like user registration, people exchanging messages and sending email notifications for people's actions (and many more).

Currently I use PHP's `mail` function to send mails and it is working fine. I already set up a VPS and hosted the application.

My question may be a dumb question.  Do Facebook and other social networking sites use SMTP servers to send the notifications or only just any kind of PHP `mail` function?

I read somewhere that using PHP's `mail`, there is a chance of mail going to SPAM folder.  They advised using a certified SMTP server.

So, if I have to use an SMTP server:

1) Do I have to purchase a certified SMTP server separately? Or can this be hosted on same VPS whatever I have.  If so, what server software will be good for this?

2) Are there settings I have to do in SMTP servers like send unlimited messages, because we don't know how many people exchange emails in a minute, and that is totally random.

Comment: Good question, but I think it would be more tailored towards ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not really with the `mail()` function in itself, but in how you construct the emails. Messages can be treated as spam for a million and one reasons, but it is generally accepted that if you use one of the tried and tested mailer libraries, like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) (both free) there is *marginally* less chance of your messages being treated as spam.

Whether your messages get treated as spam is far more about how you construct your messages than how you send them. Another major factor is if your server sends thousands and thousands of emails all the time, so another hint is to be sparing with the emails you send out - only send them when you actually need to.

If you really want to know the answer to this question, you should do some reading on exactly how the modern email system works. Being able to build and send good emails is all about knowing how to work the system. [Start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I started using Swiftmailer and that is very much straight forward . I will check with my hosting provider about SMTP server . Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

To start: you are definitely going to have to use an SMTP server to send the emails from PHP. You can't simply throw your emails at the `mail()` function and expect it to work. You have to connect it to an SMTP server that does all of the dirty work.

However, if it's not your domain, I would suggest you don't do it. If you have the time to learn the ins and outs of email delivery and want to set up and maintain an SMTP server, by all means, go ahead.

If you'd rather focus on building your app and not worry about your emails getting delivered, I'd suggest an email delivery service. Here's a good list of services to check out:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com)
- [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com)
- [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com)

And there are plenty more out there. All of them have a free option for you to play around with, so just look for the one that fits your needs and requirements.

(**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Happy to answer any questions you might have about sending email from your app, though!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the details . I do look at your website . Thank You again